# Android ImageView:pinch 2 zoom

Tags: android

I found the below code on net but i get an error saying the method set(Matrix) is      undefined for the type Matrix

similarly i get the same error for postScale and getValues

matrix and savedMatrix are of type Matrix

```
   public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
   ImageView view = (ImageView) v;
   // make the image scalable as a matrix
   view.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);
   float scale;

   // Handle touch events here...
   switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {

   case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: //first finger down only
   savedMatrix.set(matrix);
   start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
   Log.d(TAG, "mode=DRAG" );
   mode = DRAG;
   break;
   case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: //first finger lifted
   case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: //second finger lifted
   mode = NONE;
   Log.d(TAG, "mode=NONE" );
   break;
   case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN: //second finger down
   oldDist = spacing(event); 
   Log.d(TAG, "oldDist=" + oldDist);
   // minimal distance between both the fingers
   if (oldDist > 5f) {
     savedMatrix.set(matrix);
     midPoint(mid, event);  
     mode = ZOOM;
     Log.d(TAG, "mode=ZOOM" );
   }
   break;

   case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: 
   if (mode == DRAG) 
   { //movement of first finger
     matrix.set(savedMatrix);
     if (view.getLeft() >= -392)
     {
        matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - start.x, event.getY() - start.y);
     }
   }
   else if (mode == ZOOM) { //pinch zooming
     float newDist = spacing(event);
     Log.d(TAG, "newDist=" + newDist);
     if (newDist > 5f) {
        matrix.set(savedMatrix);
        scale = newDist/oldDist; 
        matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
     }
   }
   break;
   }

   // Perform the transformation
   view.setImageMatrix(matrix);

   return true; // indicate event was handled
   }
```

Comment: What Matrix class have you imported?

Comment: You probably have imported opengl Matrix class instead of graphics Matrix class.

Comment: android.opengl.Matrix

Comment: Ok, you have imported the wrong class, you should import android.graphics.Matrix